# Extract coefficient from polynomial of 4° order in excel by linest

Tags: excel, polynomials, coefficients

I want to exctract in a cell the coefficient of a polynomial regression (4th order) in excel (the same obtained by the graph).

My data are:

```
y        x
158,6   26,37541865
165     26,3985226
211     22,8663368
255,1   20,50228679
280     19,23051258
321,4   17,87086469
357     16,78427092
370,4   16,38371385
407     15,45677574
429,2   14,93514757
```

I used the following formula:

```
=INDICE(REGR.LIN(A50:A58;B50:B58^{1\2\3};1;0);1)
```

(in english is `=Index(Linest(A50:A58;B50:B58^{1\2\3};1;0);1)`)

The symbol `'\'` substitutes `','` or `';'`

I didn't get the same value that I obtain by using the regression in the graph.

Do you have same suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `...B50:B58^{1\2\3}...` is only 3th order. And are you sure that your graph really has the values in column `A` on the vertical axis (`y`) ? If you select `A`and `B` for creating a chart, then  the default will be `x` in `A` and `y` in `B`.